# Calculate date difference using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

How to calculate the time difference using jquery?

Example:

> First 4 hours is equivalent to 0.5 
>   Whole day is equivalent to 1.0

Example working hours

> 8am to 12pm is 0.5 
>   1pm to 5pm will equivalent to 0.5 also.

and 24 hours is equivalent to 1.0

for example:

> 11/11/2014 08:00am 11/11/2014 12:00pm

result is 0.5..

Thanks

```js
$('#get').click(function(){
    var startDate = new Date($('#dpd1').val());
    var startTime =(''+ $("#time1").val()).split(":");

    var endDate = new Date($('#dpd2').val());
    var endTime = (''+ $("#time2").val()).split(":");

    startDate.setHours(parseInt(startTime[0]));
    startDate.setMinutes(parseInt(startTime[1]));

    endDate.setHours(parseInt(endTime[0]));
    endDate.setMinutes(parseInt(endTime[1]));

    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var differenceDays = (diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    var differenceHours = ((diff) % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/ (1000 * 60 * 60);
    $('#totalleave').val(Math.round(differenceDays) + ' days ' +Math.round(differenceHours) + ' hours' );
});
```

Comment: Have you tried any code, and if so can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1 = new Date(d1), date2 = new Date(date2);

var hourDiff = date1.getHours()-date2.getHours();
```

now manipulate this `hourDiff` the way you want.